# How to convert pixels into dip(Density Independent Pixels) in Android

Tags: android

In my Android application I have pixels(69px) and I need to convert this pixels into dip(Density Independent Pixels).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this will be helpful

```
Resources r = getResources();
float dp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 69, r.getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: No it is giving the same value.I mean the value of pixel as dip

Answer (score 10):

Just divide your value in pixels by DisplayMetrics.density.

Comment: Which is correct: to divide or to multiply as in @Khushboo's example?

Comment: Divide. The formula shown by @Khushboo convertes dp to px. On an xhdpi display, DisplayMetrics.density == 2.0f. Since 1 dp == 1 px on an mdpi display and 1 dp == 2 px on an xhdpi display, you need to divide to convert dp to px, not the other way around.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
public int convertDiptoPx(int pixel){

    float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int dips=(int) ((pixel * scale) + 0.5f);
    logMessage("Px=" +pixel+"  DipValue="+dips );   
    return dips;
}
```

Editted:

```
public int convertPxtoDip(int pixel){
    float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int dips=(int) ((pixel / scale) + 0.5f);
    return dips;
}
```

Comment: I have editted the code now. Mistakenly, I posted the answer of opposite conversion.

Comment: You can check the conversion at this website:-   http://labs.skinkers.com/content/android_dp_px_calculator/.